# Error: timed out trying to communicate with ClearCase remote server

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I got the following error while creating Clearcase UCM snapshot view. Why it occurs?

What is the remedy for this?

```
---------------------------
ClearCase View Tool
---------------------------
Error creating view -- 'My_SnapView'.

Unable to get host information for host "hostname": timed out trying to communicate with ClearCase remote server.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing to check is if your local service "albd" is running.
If the Atria Location Broker isn't running, no communication will be possible between the ClearCase client on your workstation and the server.

The other, of course, would be to check if there is some kind of network issue (can you ping the ClearCase server?)

Comment: Yes i verified that albd server is running and i am able to ping the 'hostname'.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: then post your command line to create your view. I will debug it.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Check also on the server is the view server is up and running (look also for process with albd). Check also any process used to access your server (we are using samba to access view and vob storages, so we had to restart from time to time `smdb` and `nmdb` processes)